# Is it possible to generate an OTP for certain operation in firebase?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, one-time-password

I need an OTP code for permit certain user activity.

Suppose I have an group, now I want to add people to this group via group tag.
I want when someone enter the group tag then i will send him an OTP for verification.
Is it possible in firebase?

If there are another way to implement my thought it will be helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: So I don't believe there is default behaviour for this, but you can write cloud code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default behavior for this, but there a trick which I have used.
In firebase, you get an option "Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number"
here is the link for steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth.

So you can use this to generate OTP and once your user enters the OTP an account with the given number will be created in Firebase which you can delete using the "currentuser.delete()" function as soon as OTP is verified.

Comment below if you need the code which I have used in my app(for OTP verification).

Comment: My ultimate goal was to generate an 4 or 6 digit numeric OTP code without using any phone number. But thank you I will check your idea out. Thank you.